MCP9601 Inaccurate Temperature Reading / Warm Casing
I am looking for some general advice regarding an application I have using an MCP9601.
I am able to communicate with the MCP9601, and I am getting changing temperature values from the TH register (tested with a lighter, temperature got above 500C before I stopped checking). My issue seems to be that the ambient/baseline temperature is way off what it should be, I am reading 50C when it should be somewhere around 20C. My cold junction temperature (as reported by the MCP9601) is also at around 50C. In addition to this, I noticed that the MCP package/casing itself is noticeably warm to the touch.
I had a custom PCB made for my project, and this is the first time I have soldered a QFN package, so I'm not sure if that could be related? Maybe poor thermal conductivity to the thermal pad? I also note that I failed to keep the MCP particularly close to the terminals, which was a recommendation from the data sheet. MCP is at least 0.5" / 12mm from the terminals. I am not currently in a place where I can add snapshots of the board design, else I would embed them here.
To summarize, I believe the MCP is working correctly, and that it is likely a PCB design error on my part causing this issue, but I am looking for external feedback.
It's worth noting that I also have a breakout board from Adafruit that I had previously used for testing (using MCP9600, not 01), it reports the correct temperature (using the exact same microcontroller program), and the package does not get warm to the touch.
====== Edit to add context ======
I did take some temperature measurements around my PCB using an infrared thermometer. MCP was creating the most heat at about 35C.
I tested the other board I made (I have two identical), the MCP on the second board exhibits the same behavior, casing gets warm.
====== Edit to add a couple KiCAD snapshots ======
Please excuse any PCB design issues, I am not a professional when it comes to this. I try to follow what I understand to be best practice, but my understanding could be wrong. This is my 3rd ever design.




The chip itself typically draws 300uA so it should certainly not get noticeably warm. That's 1.5mW with a 5V supply. The temperature you say you are seeing suggests a dissipation of more than 500mW, hundreds of times higher.
So either the chip is heating itself or something else on the board is heating the chip, assuming your ambient is around 25°C. Only you know what else is on the board.
It's possible that a mistake like not properly connecting the EP pad to ground could cause this sort of thing, but there are other possible problems too. It seems too high a dissipation even for a shorted output, but there's not enough information to speculate on that. Damaged chips can also cause similar symptoms.
Since the CJC is on-chip, the chip should be kept isothermal with the junctions from thermocouple material to copper. That's where the short distance comes in. But the errors from that will be relatively small (the temperature difference between the two points) normally. Needless to say, you don't want anything else on your board or nearby that gets remotely warm if you care about accuracy. Ideally, you would run a ribbon cable or something like that off to some potted isothermal block with thermocouple material wires coming in and copper conductors for the power supply and I2C.

Upon seeing the schematic- there are 6 push-pull outputs (Alert 1 to 4, OC and SC alert), all shorted to ground. A possibility I mentioned above. That will cause heating if any one of them is high. Here is the Adafruit board schematic:

As you can see those pins are brought out to a header, but are otherwise left open.
With CMOS chips, unused inputs should be connected to a valid logic state (which may require an external connection or pull-up resistor or pull-down resistor if there is no on-chip resistor) and unused outputs should generally be left open.
Also, it's usually a good idea, especially on early versions of a board, to use resistors or jumpers rather than direct connections to Vdd or GND because you can easily change them.
Given the CJC presence right on the die, I would suggest drawing minimum current from those outputs, for example, you could use them to switch a MOSFET gate with a 10kΩ series resistor to control an LED rather that switching the LED directly.

I am fairly confident that nothing else on the board is heating up, but I will take some temperature measurements later to confirm that. There are no significant sources of heat anywhere on this board, the worst would be from the Pickit4 when it's connected, but highly doubtful that it's related.
Thermal pad is not isolated from entire board ground, which could also be a contributor.

The thermal pad is also an electrical connection and it must be grounded, as per the datasheet. If you failed to solder it, that could be the cause of your problems.

Yes, understood, I just mean it's all connected as one large mass of ground plane, data sheet application example shows the pad connected to ground through traces and vias only, not surrounded by a monolithic ground plane as I have done. In any case, it SHOULD be connected to ground, though I do not have a good way to check that. Paste was applied and given the chance to reflow.

After taking some temperature readings with a simple infrared thermometer, the MCP is absolutely the hottest thing on the board by a mile. Thermometer only reported 35C but doubt it is particularly accurate.

We can look at your schematic, PCB layout and implementation … but if you have  a few chips, swapping the one you have for a fresh one would not be a bad move at this point. After looking at the schematic and layout and doubled checking and comparing to the working commercial module schematic and layout. Adafruit publishes excellent documentation, so you have that going for you.

I just added some snapshots of the PCB and schematic that I put together, but you make a valid point. I have looked at the board design for the Adafruit but not in much detail. Also, I have made two of these boards and both MCP's exhibit the same behavior (both getting hot).

The second board is an important piece of information- but looking at the schematic I see 6 push-pull outputs, all deliberately shorted to ground. That will do it.

ding-dong Cut the Alerts.

I am going to mark this as answered, as I expect speff is correct. Frankly, I had forgotten that those were outputs when making my circuit and blindly followed my old rule of grounding unused pins, which is the wrong call with outputs. I am going to try to cut the solder/pads to see if I can salvage the boards and rectify the issue.
